# Add subview to another view

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller, subview, ios5

With two ViewControllers, MyView 1 and MyView 2, is there possible to add a subview to MyView2 from MyView1.m?

I have tried:

```
MyView2 * screen = [[MyView2 alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[screen.view addSubView:mySubView];
```

But my new instance of MyView 2 has no connection to the 'visible' ViewController on MyView2, right?

To clarify, the ViewController that is showing, is MyView1. I want MyView1 to be able to add a subview to the MyView2 view.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're confusing viewControllers with views, or at least your question is. Maybe it's something like this you're looking for -

```
MyViewController2 *myViewController2 = [[[MyViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil] autorelease];

[myViewController2.view addSubView:mySubView];
// add any other views to myViewController2's view

[self.view addSubView:myViewController2.view]; // adding the view to VC1's view
```

If you want to be able to continue adding stuff throughout MyViewController1, you should declare either myViewController2 or its view as a retained property.

Answer (score 1):

You could have MyView1 controller save some information in a common object in your app so that when MyView2 reappears it can add the subview to its view if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming MyView2 is a subclass of UIViewController, there is no `addSubView:` method on the viewcontroller itself.  Instead, you want to add the subView to your view controller's `view`, like this:

```
[screen.view addSubview:mySubView];
```

Comment: Thanks, but that wasn't really the problem, I already had screen.view in my code. The problem is I want to change MyView2's view from MyView1.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
[MyView1.view addSubView:MyView2];
[self.view addSubview:MyView1];
```